# High Performance Calculation of Sums and Returns in Go

Tags: performance, go

I am writing a finance library with the intention to have the best of Golang's performance.

The function **Re** calculates the returns of a float list, and function **Sum** calculates the sum of float list.

```golang
//Calculate returns
func Re(data []float64) []float64 {

    re_ := make([]float64, len(data))
    for i := 1; i < len(data); i++ {
        re_[i] = ( (data[i]/data[i-1])-1)
    }

    return re_
}

// sum of float64 list
func Sum(floatList []float64) float64 {

    var totalx float64
    for _, valuex := range floatList {
        totalx += valuex
    }

    return totalx
}
```

is there any further possible optimisation on these two functions or another more performant way to write them?

Comment: don't allocate. period. i am sure you can rewrite it without allocations. btw, _re[0] is never set (...).

Comment: @mh-cbon:  In the context of a finance library, your comments make no sense to me. `_re[0]` is set, it's set to the zero value.  Allocating a slice for the values of the computed finance returns is necessary.

Comment: _re[0] is initialized to its zero value, not set (just why commenting that ?). Maybe you have right regarding the "finance" context, however op asks `is there any further possible optimisation on these two functions or another more performant way to write them?`. anyways, for a finance application, using float64 is unexpected. maybe some optimizations around that are also possible and should be commented. maybe op should more precisely define optimization, it seems there is some discrepancies.

Comment: @mh-cbon: "`_re[0]` [sic] is initialized to its zero value, **not set** (just why commenting that ?)."  The Go Programming Language Specification says: When storage is allocated for a variable and no explicit initialization is provided, each element of such a variable is **set** to the zero value for its type: `0` for numeric types. Therefore, when `re_ := make([]float64, len(data))` is executed, `re_[0]` is **set** to the zero value for `float64`, which is `0`, when `len(data) > 0`. Your claim that: "`_re[0]` [sic] is **never set** (...)" is false.

Comment: @mh-cbon: "for a finance application, using `float64` is **unexpected**." For a finance application in Go, using `float64` is **expected**.

Comment: @mh-cbon: "maybe op should more precisely define optimization, it seems there is some discrepancies." What discrepancies? The OP defined optimization precisely enough: time (CPU) and space (memory).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Go, when you want to measure function performance, use the Go `testing` package to run a benchmark.

For example,

`returns.go`:

```
package finance

// Calculate returns
func Re(data []float64) []float64 {
    var re []float64
    if len(data) > 0 {
        re = make([]float64, len(data))
    }
    for i := 1; i < len(data); i++ {
        if data[i-1] != 0 {
            re[i] = (data[i] / data[i-1]) - 1
        }
    }
    return re
}

// Calculate sum
func Sum(data []float64) float64 {
    var sum float64
    for _, x := range data {
        sum += x
    }
    return sum
}
```

`returns_test.go`:

```
package finance

import "testing"

func BenchmarkRe(b *testing.B) {
    data := make([]float64, 5*12)
    for i := range data {
        data[i] = float64(i)
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        Re(data)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSum(b *testing.B) {
    data := make([]float64, 5*12)
    for i := range data {
        data[i] = float64(i)
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        Sum(data)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test returns.go returns_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkRe-4     7545566   156 ns/op     480 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkSum-4   28272992    41.5 ns/op     0 B/op    0 allocs/op
$
```

I looked at some other alternatives, but that's the fastest.

Note: I fixed your divide-by-zero bug.